# Animation before routing to another page using react, redux and react-router-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-redux

I am working on an app that is built on the frontend using react, redux and react-router-redux for navigation and i don't have much frontend expirience.
 When i need to perform routing from one page to another, first i need to show animation, and then after the animation finishes, i need to navigate to another page. 
I was thinking about firing one action that will add the animation class, and when that action finishes, should i use something similar like setTimeout so when animation ends, the push action to be fired from react-router-redux ? 
What are other ways to find solution to the problem ?

Comment: Your proposal of setting a timeout sounds reasonable, but it might be even better if the action that sets the animation class returns a promise, sets the timeout itself, and then resolves the promise when the timeout is finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [react-addons-css-transition-group](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html)

> `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` is based on `ReactTransitionGroup` and is an
>   easy way to perform CSS transitions and animations when a React
>   component enters or leaves the DOM. It's inspired by the excellent
>   ng-animate library.

This will trigger a transition in your main layout every time you change a route

**css**

```
.example-enter {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}

.example-enter.example-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.example-leave {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}

.example-leave.example-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

**js**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group'

const App = ({ children, location }) => (
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><Link to="/page1">Page 1</Link></li>
      <li><Link to="/page2">Page 2</Link></li>
    </ul>

    <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
      component="div"
      transitionName="example"
      transitionEnterTimeout={500}
      transitionLeaveTimeout={500}
    >
      {React.cloneElement(children, {
        key: location.pathname
      })}
    </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
  </div>
)
```

[Full example](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/tree/master/examples/animations)